# Java netbeans : how to send a different value to JFrame in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

so I have a frame 1 and frame 2 
in the frame 1 by having 4 and has 1 JButton JTextField 
at 4 JTextField a user to input an integer value .. 
after the user input, the user presses a JButton and JFrame will feature 2 ..

and in the second frame I have 1 JTextArea which will print out a value that a user input

so how to send values ​​from frame 1 to frame 2?

Comment: Could you please provide some code please? :) Thank you!

Comment: in the method I have, DDA method () which contains the code:

Answer (score 0):

inside JFrame 2, Create attributes for user inputs in Jframe 1 and create getters and setters for them.

Inside the method for clicking the jbutton, you should do following,

1. Create an object of JFrame2
2. Pass user input values to the Jframe

Now take user inputs from textfields and set them inside Jframe2 using setter methods you created.

If you dont understand this well, please post your code. It'll help others to make good answers!

Comment: actually in this project I've given constructor in which I made into a class and in Jframe1 "coba.java" I make new objeck with this code: 

     coba ar = new coba(); 

in a Jframe1 I have a method in which DDA has a code: 
     
      double X0 = Double.parseDouble (x0.getText ()); 
      double X1 = Double.parseDouble (x1.getText ()); 
      double Y0 = Double.parseDouble (y0.getText ()); 
      double Y1 = Double.parseDouble (y1.getText ()); 
      int no = 1; 
      ar.X0 = X0; 
      ar.X1 = X1; 
      ar.Y0 = Y0; 
      ar.Y1 = Y1;

Answer (score 0):

In your JFrame1,

To Handle the button action (Note that variable name of the button is jButton1)

```
     jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() { //This part can be written inside the constructor.
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
     });

        public void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

           coba ar = new coba();
           double X0 = Double.parseDouble (x0.getText ());
           double X1 = Double.parseDouble (x1.getText ());
           double Y0 = Double.parseDouble (y0.getText ());
           double Y1 = Double.parseDouble (y1.getText ());

           int no = 1; 
           ar.X0 = X0; 
           ar.X1 = X1;
           ar.Y0 = Y0; 
           ar.Y1 = Y1;

           ar.showValues();
      }
  });
```

1. In your coba.java

   ```
      void showValues() {
          jTextArea1.setText(""+X0+" "+X1+" "+Y0+" "+Y1);
      }
   ```

Hope this would help you !